# Can I get Lion (or newer) to stop asking me about Java?

Tags: java

From time to time, I get a system dialog box that asks if I want to install Java.  I always say No.

Is there a way to get it to stop asking me?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you run a program that requires java? Have you tried going into the terminal and deleted the Java executable that launches the update script?

Comment: I want it to behave just as if I'd clicked "No".  Many or most things on the Mac, when giving me a choice of Yes or No, also offer a "Don't ask again" option.

Comment: What is "the Java executable that launches the update script"?  I see JavaVM.framework in /System/Library/Frameworks/, commands in /usr/bin that symlink to commands in the framework, some more stuff in /System/Library/Java/.

Comment: There's also a couple of PrivateFrameworks.  I'm not even sure that the updater (`JLRequestRuntimeInstall`?) is among these.  Is JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current guaranteed to be the only entry point to Java?